# NightwatchJS cannot getValue within a section

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I have the following command embedded in a section:

```
verify: function (input) {
    this
        .waitForElementVisible('@value');
    this
        .getValue('.keystone-body form .field-type-text[for="name"] input[name="name"]', function(result) {
            this.assert.equal(result.value, input.value);
        });
    this
        .getValue('.keystone-body form .field-type-text[for="name"]', function(result) {
            console.log('***result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    this
        .getValue('@value', function (result) {
            console.log('***result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    return this;
},
```

As you can see in the Selenium logs, all four function calls refer to the same selector tree (the 3rd one is actually a representation of the selector tree that causes the exception to happen on the 4th one).  The first three work just fine.  However, the fourth one doesn't and generates the exception in the logs below.  Note that in the third one, I've used the same selector causing the exception and works fine.  I've gone to the page where this happens used the following query (same as the 3rd and 4th queries above) and works fine as well:

```
document.querySelector('.keystone-body form .field-type-text[for="name"]')
```

Nightwatch Logs:

```
 ✔ Element <Section[name=form],Section[name=nameList],Section[name=nameField],Element[name=@value]> was visible after 64 milliseconds.
 ✔ Passed [equal]: Name Field Test 1 == Name Field Test 1
***result: {"state":"success","sessionId":"72e0085f-086a-443e-b71f-e893fcbd4fdc","hCode":484670138,"value":null,"class":"org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response","status":0}
***result: {"status":-1,"value":{"additionalInformation":"\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown","localizedMessage":"Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"css selector\",\"selector\":\".field-type-text[for=\\\"name\\\"]\"}\nFor documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html\nBuild info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'\nSystem info: host: 'XPS8500', ip: '10.0.0.208', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_31'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown","supportUrl":"http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html","systemInformation":"System info: host: 'XPS8500', ip: '10.0.0.208', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_31'","cause":null,"suppressed":[],"message":"Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"css selector\",\"selector\":\".field-type-text[for=\\\"name\\\"]\"}\nFor documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html\nBuild info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'\nSystem info: host: 'XPS8500', ip: '10.0.0.208', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_31'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown","hCode":2047706588,"class":"org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException","buildInformation":{"buildRevision":"4c2593c","buildTime":"2016-02-11 19:06:42","releaseLabel":"2.52.0","hCode":825790507,"class":"org.openqa.selenium.internal.BuildInfo"}},"errorStatus":7,"error":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."}
 ERROR: Unable to locate element: "Section[name=form],Section[name=nameList],Section[name=nameField],Element[name=@value]" using: recursion
    at Section.getValue (C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\page-object\command-wrapper.js:103:25)
    at Section.NameList.sections.nameField.commands.verify (C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\test\e2e\adminUI\pages\lists\name.js:35:9)
    at Object.module.exports.Name field can be created via the initial modal (C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\test\e2e\adminUI\tests\group005Fields\uxTestNameField.js:51:5)
    at Module.call (C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\module.js:63:34)
    at C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\testcase.js:97:29
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\node_modules\nightwatch\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\node_modules\nightwatch\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\node_modules\nightwatch\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\node_modules\nightwatch\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\node_modules\nightwatch\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\Joe\git\prs\node_modules\nightwatch\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
 ERROR: Unable to locate element: "Section[name=form],Section[name=nameList],Section[name=nameField],Element[name=@value]" using: recursion
```

Selenium Logs:

```
18:19:44.893 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.cssSelector: .keystone-body])^M
18:19:44.901 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.cssSelector: .keystone-body]^M
18:19:44.905 INFO - Executing: [find child elements: 20 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body], By.cssSelector: form])^M
18:19:44.911 INFO - Done: [find child elements: 20 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body], By.cssSelector: form]^M
18:19:44.915 INFO - Executing: [find child elements: 22 [[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form], By.cssSelector: .field-type-text[for="name"]])^M
18:19:44.915 INFO - Executing: [find child elements: 21 [[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form], By.cssSelector: .field-type-text[for="name"]])^M
18:19:44.924 INFO - Done: [find child elements: 22 [[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form], By.cssSelector: .field-type-text[for="name"]]^M
18:19:44.932 INFO - Done: [find child elements: 21 [[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form], By.cssSelector: .field-type-text[for="name"]]^M
18:19:44.934 INFO - Executing: [find child elements: 23 [[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form]] -> css selector: .field-type-text[for="name"]], By.cssSelector: input[name="name"]])^M
18:19:44.940 INFO - Done: [find child elements: 23 [[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form]] -> css selector: .field-type-text[for="name"]], By.cssSelector: input[name="name"]]^M
18:19:44.943 INFO - Executing: [is displayed: 24 [[[[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form]] -> css selector: .field-type-text[for="name"]]] -> css selector: input[name="name"]]])^M
18:19:44.954 INFO - Done: [is displayed: 24 [[[[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form]] -> css selector: .field-type-text[for="name"]]] -> css selector: input[name="name"]]]^M
18:19:44.956 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.cssSelector: .keystone-body form .field-type-text[for="name"] input[name="name"]])^M
18:19:44.962 INFO - Done: [find element: By.cssSelector: .keystone-body form .field-type-text[for="name"] input[name="name"]]^M
18:19:44.964 INFO - Executing: [get element attribute: 24 [[[[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form]] -> css selector: .field-type-text[for="name"]]] -> css selector: input[name="name"]], value])^M
18:19:44.970 INFO - Done: [get element attribute: 24 [[[[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form]] -> css selector: .field-type-text[for="name"]]] -> css selector: input[name="name"]], value]^M
18:19:44.973 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.cssSelector: .keystone-body form .field-type-text[for="name"]])^M
18:19:44.978 INFO - Done: [find element: By.cssSelector: .keystone-body form .field-type-text[for="name"]]^M
18:19:44.980 INFO - Executing: [get element attribute: 23 [[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form]] -> css selector: .field-type-text[for="name"]], value])^M
18:19:44.987 INFO - Done: [get element attribute: 23 [[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form]] -> css selector: .field-type-text[for="name"]], value]^M
18:19:44.991 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.cssSelector: .keystone-body])^M
18:19:44.997 INFO - Done: [find element: By.cssSelector: .keystone-body]^M
18:19:45.000 INFO - Executing: [find child element: 20 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body], By.cssSelector: form])^M
18:19:45.007 INFO - Done: [find child element: 20 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body], By.cssSelector: form]^M
18:19:45.012 INFO - Executing: [find child element: 21 [[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (237d3a34-9cc3-484e-8d5a-8a01ceb65c41)] -> css selector: .keystone-body]] -> css selector: form], By.cssSelector: .field-type-text[for="name"]])^M
18:19:45.253 WARN - Exception thrown^M
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".field-type-text[for=\"name\"]"}
```

I have gone rounds on this one and cannot seem to arrive at the root cause.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the page had a very embedded small form that somehow was throwing off the generated section selector.

Comment: and how did you solve that? i have the same problem, i'm going round and round, and i don't manage to solve it. It seems i have just opened a same question for that, maybe it's a duplicate.

Comment: @anasarbescu in my case I just had to make the selector more specific to target the actual correct form.

Comment: ok, thanks, maybe i can play around more with mine too, maybe i get lucky. :-)

Comment: What's the link to your SO question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112583/cannot-locate-element-using-recursion-after-it-found-it-as-visible