# Cannot locate element using recursion after it found it as visible

Tags: javascript, recursion, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

**My Problem:**

I am trying to click options in a dropdown with Nightwatch, using sections in page objects. I'm not sure if it's a problem with the section declaration or i'm missing something scope-related. Problem is that it finds the element as visible, but when it tries to click it will throw error that it cannot locate it using recursion.

What could i try to do to fix this issue using sections?

**In the test:**

```
var myPage = browser.page.searchPageObject();
var mySection = searchPage.section.setResults;

// [finding and clicking the dropdown so it opens and displays the options]
browser.pause (3000);

browser.expect.section('@setResults').to.be.visible.before(1000);
myPage.myFunction(mySection, '18');
```

**In the page object:**

```
var searchKeywordCommands = {
    myFunction: function (section, x) {
        section.expect.element('@set18').to.be.visible.before(2000);
        if (x == '18') section.click('@set18');
        //[...]
};

module.exports = {
    //[.. other elements and commands..]
    sections: {
        setResults: {
            selector: '.select-theme-result', //have also tried with '.select-content' and '.select-options' but with the same result
            elements: {
                set18: '.select-option[data-value="18"]',
                set36: '.select-option[data-value="36"]' //etc

            }}}}
```

Here is my source code:
[image]

When i run this piece of core, it seems to find the section, finds the element visible (i also can clearly see that it opens the dropdown and shows the options) but when trying to click any option, i get the error:  `ERROR: Unable to locate element: Section[name=setResults], Element[name=@set18]" using: recursion`

Here is the full error:
[image]

**My attempts:**

I have tried to declare that `set18` selector as an individual element instead of inside of the section and everything works fine this way, but won't work inside of the section. I have also tried all the selectors available to define the section's selector, but it won't work with any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i am doing with(LOL) 
I assume steps would be (find dropbox - click dropbox - select value).

```
var getValueElement = {
        getValueSelector: function (x) {
            return 'li[data-value="'+ x + '"]';
        }
}; 

module.exports = {
    //[.. other elements and commands..]
    sections: {
        setResults: {
            commands:[getValueElement],
            selector: 'div[class*="select-theme-result"', //* mean contains,sometime class is too long and unique,also because i am lazy.
            elements: {
                setHighlight:'li[class*="select-option-highlight"]',
                setSelected:'li[class*="select-option-selected"]', 
                //set18: 'li[data-value="18"]',
                //set36: 'li[data-value="36"]' 
                // i think getValueFunction is better,what if you have 100+ of set.

            }}}}
```

In your test

```
var myPage = browser.page.searchPageObject();
var mySection = searchPage.section.setResults;

// [finding and clicking the dropdown so it opens and displays the options]
mySection
     .click('@dropboxSelector')
     .waitForElementVisible('@setHighlight',5000,false,
          function(){
            var set18 = mySection.getValueElement(18);
            mySection.click(set18);
            });
```

Ps:in my case(i think your case also), dropbox or any small third-party js framework which is used many times in your web app, so better create a different PageObject for it,make pageObject/section is simple as possible.

Comment: first of all, how can i access that getValueElement function? it throws error that it's not a function for both mySection.getValueElement(18) and myPage.getValueElement(18).

Comment: ok, i think i managed, there needs to be a separate function in the command, not the command needs to be a function. but now i get:  ERROR: Unable to locate element: "li[data-value=18]" using: css selector

Comment: Can you open your browser - F12 - in Element tab,find the shortest string for "li[data-value=18]" CSS selector ?

Comment: yes, of course it was there. but i figured meanwhile the problem, the getValueElement function was missing the " "